# Symfony 2: route defined in annotation not visible from by Twig's path()

Tags: php, routes, annotations, symfony, twig

I encountered a problem, have the following:

DefaultController with a simple action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register")
 * @Template
 */
public function indexAction() {
    $oForm = $this->createForm(new RegisterType());
    return array(
        'form'  => $oForm->createView()
    );
}
```

In my twig template I try to use:

```
<form action="{{ path('register') }}" method="post"></form>
```

But I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "register" does not exist.") in EBTSCustomerBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 2.
```

When I explicitely define a "register" route in app/config/routing.yml:

```
register:
  pattern:  /register
  defaults: { _controller: EBTSCustomerBundle:Controller:Default:index }
```

Then it works fine. Can't find any reasonable docs about it, I thought that routes defined via annotations should be visible in the whole application.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Routes by annotations still need to be imported into routing.yml as so:

```
AcmeHelloBundle:
  resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Controller"
  type: annotation
```

This will tell the routing to scan the `Controller` directory of the `Acme\HelloBundle` and import all routes.

You can find more information about routing with annotations **[here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)**. That link will also tell you how to activate routes as I have shown above.

Also, I noticed that your route annotation needs the `name` parameter to be accessible through `register` using the `path` function otherwise it'd be accessed through `acme_bundlename_controllername_actionname`:

```
@Route("/register", name="register")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that import in my previous note, routes from my bundle were imported just like you wrote (resource: @AcmeHelloBundle...), but the missing name="register" part in my annotation was causing the problem. Thanks for your input, it really helped!

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Comment: Had the same problem...turned out my "name" in the annotation was set incorrectly.  Thanks.